# Android O not displaying foregrounded service notification

Tags: android-8.0-oreo

As per the documentation I have made the changes in the app to start services in the background using `context.startForegroundService(Intent)` and then calling `startForeground` in the service as before.

```
NotificationCompat.Builder notification = new 
NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.icon)
            .setContentText("Content")
            .setOngoing(true)
            .setContentInfo("Info")
            .setContentTitle("Title");
startForeground(1, notification.build());
```

This correctly displays the notification on an Android N device but on an Android O device it does not display a notification it only displays the new " is running in the background... tap for more details on battery and data usage"

Is there something missing to get the notification to display correctly on Android O?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, use a channel as constructor parameter of `NotificationCompat` class.

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean by this?

Comment: Oh you mean the new constructor in the beta support libraries? Unfortunately, I cannot use the beta libraries because of external restrictions. I'm just making a library future proof for a user, I'll have to update the libraries when they move to v26

Comment: Yes, use v26.0.0-beta2

Comment: This doesn't work in O, my notification doesn't show in O even when I create the channel. It shows on all other versions. even made sure to call startForegroundService instead of startService

Answer (score 3):

The answer above doesn't work for me. You have to create channel in order to work and then pass the channel id.

```
NotificationManager notificationManager =
        (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

String channelId = "some_channel_id";
CharSequence channelName = "Some Channel";
int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW;
NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(channelId, channelName, importance);
notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
```

Then create a notfication with the same cannelId

```
new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
```